# Python bigquery error: QueryJob._blocking_poll() got an unexpected keyword argument 'retry'

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a flask app which tries to query bigquery but no success I keep getting error:

```
QueryJob._blocking_poll() got an unexpected keyword argument 'retry'
```

I have tried the client as in sample documentation by GCP which looks like this `client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)` but also tried creating a service account and attaching permissions biquery job create: `client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('./bigquery-sa-keys.json')`

Yet I keep getting same error, this is how the function looks like:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from google.cloud import bigquery
# ...
project_id = 'my-proj-id'
dataset_id = 'example_dataset'
# ...
@app.route("/users")
def get_users():
    try:
        # Initialize a BigQuery client
        client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('./bigquery-sa-keys.json')
     
        query_job = client.query(query)
        results = query_job.result()

        users = [dict(row) for row in results]
        return jsonify(users)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return f"An error occurred: {str(e)}"
```